# Copying a line number to a file

Tags: grep

I created a file ~/mayhemnum.txt, I tried to add the line number of the word mayhem from the file /usr/share/dict/words as its only word. This was the command I used and it didn't work. I did check the correct line number for the word and its 5.

echo "5" > ~/mayhemnum.txt

Comment: it said the output wasn't correct. I double checked the line number for the word and it said 5

Comment: I redid it double checked the line number and I fixed it. Sometimes I just need to put it out there I guess.

Comment: you just did an `echo "xxx" > file` it has nothing to do with line number, word etc.  you updated the file content with `"xxx"`, in your case, `5`. paste example, what do you have and what do you want to have as output. why is it tagged with `grep`

Answer (score -1):

echo 5 > ~/mayhemnum.txt

this was the correct command that worked

Comment: This has nothing to do with `grep` and has the exact same effect as the command mentioned in the question.